# Finding angle between a given sky position and ecliptic pole

Tags: observational-astronomy, coordinate

Given a right ascension in degrees and declination in degrees (say, 88 degrees RA, -63 degrees DEC) I want to find the angle between that location and the ecliptic pole (90 degrees RA, -66 degrees DEC... are these the right values? What are the decimals following the 66? Most of my values that I'm working with are similar to the one I give, so which ecliptic pole, if any, does this correspond to?) How would I find this angle, I need a convenient formula (such as a dot product to find this angle). Thank you!

Comment: The question about finding the angle between two celestial positions is a duplicate of other questions, such as How to calculate the angle formed between 2 planets? https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/26625/how-to-calculate-the-angle-formed-between-2-planets

Answer (score 1):

The angle between an ecliptic pole and another sky position is complementary to the [ecliptic latitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecliptic_coordinate_system) of that position.
To find ecliptic (λ, β) coordinates, one method is to convert the equatorial (α, δ) to Cartesian form:
$$ \begin{align}
x_\mathrm{equ} &= \cos \alpha \cos \delta \\
y_\mathrm{equ} &= \sin \alpha \cos \delta \\
z_\mathrm{equ} &= \sin \delta
\end{align}$$
then rotate by ε = 23.44° on the x axis:
$$ \begin{align}
x_\mathrm{ecl} &= x_\mathrm{equ} \\
y_\mathrm{ecl} &= y_\mathrm{equ} \cos \varepsilon + z_\mathrm{equ} \sin \varepsilon \\
z_\mathrm{ecl} &= z_\mathrm{equ} \cos \varepsilon - y_\mathrm{equ} \sin \varepsilon
\end{align} $$
and convert to spherical form:
$$ \begin{align}
\lambda &= \mathtt{atan2}(y_\mathrm{ecl}, x_\mathrm{ecl}) \\
\beta &= \arcsin z_\mathrm{ecl}
\end{align} $$

If you are not interested in the ecliptic longitude λ, you can express the ecliptic latitude as
$$ \beta = \arcsin (\sin \delta \cos \varepsilon - \sin \alpha \cos \delta \sin \varepsilon) $$
Then the angle off the north ecliptic pole (α=18h0m, δ=+66.56°) is 90° - β.

Working your example (α=5h52m, δ=-63°),
I get (λ=75.63°, β=-86.34°),
and the angle off the south ecliptic pole (α=6h0m, δ=-66.56°) is β + 90° = 3.66°.

Comment: `+1` Though not necessary, it looks like you are already close to including a second answer using dot product as mentioned in the last line of the question.